# Azure DevOps NodeJs Client Create Release

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, azure-devops

I have trouble with the azure nodejs client for the devops api (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api)

Basically, I want to create a Release using something like the following code

```
const azdev = require("azure-devops-node-api")
const interfaces = require("azure-devops-node-api/interfaces/ReleaseInterfaces")
// your collection url
let orgUrl = "REDACTED";
let token = "REDACTED";

let authHandler = azdev.getPersonalAccessTokenHandler(token); 
let connection = new azdev.WebApi(orgUrl, authHandler); 
const releaseApiObject = await connection.getReleaseApi();
const new_release = releaseApiObject.createRelease();
```

The problem here is the createRelease method. I cannot figure out what arguments it has to take. Can someone tell me what the

`createRelease(releaseStartMetadata: ReleaseInterfaces.ReleaseStartMetadata, project: string): Promise<ReleaseInterfaces.Release>;`

There is no documentation on what the releasestartmetadata is or how i can create it.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: You can view the source code for ReleaseStartMetadata here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/blob/master/api/interfaces/ReleaseInterfaces.ts. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the reference pointed by Gaurav above, you may also refer to the corresponding [REST API definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1), which presents the [request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1#request-body) and response parameters in a much readable form. :) There is also an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1#examples) given for reference.

Hope this helps.